# Remove readonly property

Tags: jquery

I need a text field to be readonly if it contains value else editable.

Here's what I did

```
if ($("#prq_purcatalogkey").val() != null) {

    $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop('readonly', true);
}
else {
    $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').removeProp("readonly");

}
```

but readonly doesn't work properly, the field is always readonly whether it contains a value or not! .

I have tried

```
$('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop('readonly', true);
```

also

```
$('#prqitms_purcatalogd').removeAttr('readonly');
```

but none works.

Comment: so you want same textbox as a readonly if it contains value or you have 2 different textboxes?

Comment: Where is this code? Have you put it inside a listener, like `.on('change')`? If not then it will only run once on page load.

Comment: `val()` will never be `NULL`.  It returns an empty string if there is no value IIRC.

Comment: the same textbox to be readonly if it contains value, if it doesn't contain value I want it editable.

Comment: @stef I put it inside a function in a script.

Comment: You're checking a different element in the conditional (#prq_purcatalogkey). Shouldn't you be cheking if #prqitms_purcatalogd value is empty? (val() of a textarea won't return null if it's empty)

Answer (score 7):

You might try

`$('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop('readonly', false);`

instead of `.removeAttr()`

As suggested in the comments, you will want this to fire when the element is changed, so attach it to the `.change()` event handler.

```
$("#prq_purcatalogkey").change( function(){
if ( $(this).val() == '' ){
    $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop('readonly', false);
} else {
    $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop( "readonly", true );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make textbox readonly if it contains value using following code. This is based on your comment.

```
if ($("#prqitms_purcatalogd").val() != '') {

    $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').attr('readonly', true);
}
else {
    $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').attr("readonly", false);

}
```

I have working JSFiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/thatt5zn/)

Comment: Yep.  The only problem with the original code was that it tested `value` against null.  `value` returns a non-null string.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes. the problem was .val() against null and it never returns null.
 Thank You to all of you .

Answer (score 2):

To remove readonly property do:

```
$('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop("readonly", false); // Element(s) are now enabled.
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try below Approach...

```
var fieldValue = $("#prq_purcatalogkey").val();
if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue != "") {
 $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').attr('readonly', 'true');
}else{
 $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').removeAttr('readonly');
}
```

or there is one more way.

```
 var fieldValue = $("#prq_purcatalogkey").val();
    if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue != "") {
     $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop("disabled", false);
    }else{
     $('#prqitms_purcatalogd').prop("disabled", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above-given solutions and nothing seems to work for me, but I managed to find a workaround and it is by using pure javascript.

Even though this question is almost 3 years old I hope this answer reach anyone who might run into this issue.

```
 document.getElementById("prqitms_purcatalogd").readOnly = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because many have written `$('selector').attr("readonly", false);` I want to mention that this will not work. 
**When readonly present, it specifies that an input field is read-only, either is =true, =false, =whatever.**

So proper way to go with JQuery is `.removeAttr("readonly");`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly.